# How do I pass Scala enums as parameters?

Tags: scala, enums

My Enumeration is as follows

```
object Market extends Enumeration {

  type Market = Value
  val ASX = Value("ASX")
  val LSE = Value("LSE")

}
```

then

```
class MyClass (currentMarket: Market) {
}
```

Results in the following:

not found: type Market

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to import the enumeration:

```
import Market._
```

It's more common, though, to just write `Market.Value` to refer to the enumeration type.
That also saves you the type alias in `Market`.

Comment: Will this work as a parameter even if `Market` is an object and not a class ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout yes - that's exactly how I have it and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
import Market

class MyClass (currentMarket: Market.Market) {
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.